# iOS test flight build missing from builds drop down?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

So here is what I'm dealing with:
[image]

Version 0.2 and 0.1 both have items in the drop down but version 0.25 comes up blank.

Am I missing something or has iTunes Connect just gotten confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue, resolved by adding the `beta-reports-active` entitlement to entitlements.plist.

`<key>beta-reports-active</key>`

Related is Apple's documentation on the entitlement here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1830/_index.html

Which states:

> ...to allow App Store code signed builds to be tested using iTunes Connect

Answer (score 2):

Using my AppStoreDistribution provisioning profile instead of my adhocdistribution profile to build the .ipa did the trick for me.

I would not recommend adding the beta-reports-active key manually to your entitlements, this will most likely result in conflicts.

Comment: In Visual Studio, under project Properties->iOS Bundle Signing, I had my Provisioning Profile set to Automatic - this worked ok when I only had one provisioning profile. But when I added a new test one, deploying builds to the TestFlight not longer appeared as above. Changing the Provisioning Profile to explicitly select the Distribution profile solve it - thanks Marre. A better (or any) error message from Apple would have been nice!

Comment: I'm also amazed that they let the builds disappear without any feedback at all. Glad you got your problem sorted out.